# How do I add MMDrawerController only to one tab of TabBarController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, tabbarcontroller, mmdrawercontroller

I'm using a **Tabbarcontroller** and I want a *side menu* in the first tab of the tab bar. For the side menu I'm using **MMDrawerController**.

I'm using storyboard

How should I proceed ?

Comment: tab.selectedIndex == 0, add/show the tab bar else hide it from the view.

Comment: I have written the code in appdelegate. In the code, it asks me to set a root view controller while doing alloc/init for uinavigationcontroller. If I'm setting the center view controller as root the tab bar isn't working and if I'm setting the tab bar as the root, side menu is being implemented in all the viewcontrollers in tab bar.

Comment: In Viewcontroller's viewWillAppear, hide the side where you dont need it.

Answer (score 0):

Following code is working for me, I have written this code in viewDidload of LoginScreen, In Storyboard i have created LoginScreen as rootviewController with embeded navigationController (means navigationController is storyboard entry point and LoginScreen is rootViewController).

UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *vcSideMenu = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SideMenuScreen"];
        UITabBarController *tabBar = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabBar"];
        MMDrawerController *controller = [[MMDrawerController alloc] initWithCenterViewController:tabBar leftDrawerViewController:vcSideMenu rightDrawerViewController:nil];
        CGFloat menuWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width * 0.8;
        [controller setMaximumLeftDrawerWidth:menuWidth];
        [controller setOpenDrawerGestureModeMask:MMOpenDrawerGestureModeNone];
        [controller setCloseDrawerGestureModeMask:MMCloseDrawerGestureModeAll];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:NO];